# Function defined by equations is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $$f(z) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\cos z}{z^2-(\pi/2)^2}, & \text{if }z\neq \pm \pi/2 \\
-\dfrac{1}{\pi}, & \text{if } z=\pm \pi/2
\end{cases}$$ then $f$ is an entire function.

I wrote Taylor series for $\cos z$ about the point $\pi/2$ and I got the following:
$$\cos z=-\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3+\dots;$$
which is valid for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Also we can write $\dfrac{1}{z^2-(\pi/2)^2}$ as $\dfrac{1}{(z-\pi/2)(z+\pi/2)}$. I can write that $\dfrac{1}{z+\pi/2}$ as a power about the point $\pi/2$ but this is valid for $|z-\pi/2|<\pi$.

Can anyone please show how to solve this question, please?

Comment: It suffices to show $f$ has removable singularities (with the stated value), because $f$ is clearly holomorphic everywhere except the zeros of the denominator. You're basically there; it doesn't matter that the geometric series for the denominator has finite radius. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, can you give more details? I have started to study this subject a while ago. I'd be so grateful for your help!

Comment: Being _entire_ means being holomorphic at every point of the complex plane. The cosine and the quadratic polynomial are holomorphic, so their quotient is holomorphic except perhaps where the quadratic vanishes. So, your question reduces to showing $f$ is holomorphic at two points, $\pm\pi/2$. Now, your calculations show that $f$ is holomorphic at $\pi/2$: The factors of $(z - \pi/2)$ in the cosine and in the denominator cancel. By evenness, or by a similar argument at $-\pi/2$, $f$ is holomorphic there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Being *entire* means being holomorphic at every point of the complex plane. The cosine and the quadratic polynomial are entire, so their quotient is holomorphic except perhaps where the quadratic vanishes. Your question therefore reduces to showing $f$ is holomorphic at two points, $\pm\pi/2$.

Your calculations show that the factors of $(z - \pi/2)$ in the cosine and in the denominator cancel. It follows that $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $\pi/2$, hence holomorphic by the [Riemann extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). By evenness, or by a similar argument at $-\pi/2$, $f$ is holomorphic there as well.